# Reading a Bluetooth data stream from an Arduino with iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, arduino

I'm trying to read data from an Arduino board on an iOS device via Bluetooth. In particular, I'm using the Coin Bluetooth prototype board.

While I am able to receive data on the iOS device from the Arduino, I'm having trouble making sense of the data order seen on the iOS device. On the Arduino, I'm doing something simple to start... just sending three consecutive bytes over and over:

```
void loop()
{
  mySerial.write((byte)1);
  mySerial.write((byte)2);
  mySerial.write((byte)3);
}
```

On iOS, I'm able to read the data into an NSData object, and when printing out the result in hex, I have something that looks like the following:

0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
02 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 02 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
01 02 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 02 03 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
03 02 03 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 02 03 01 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
02 02 03 01 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 01 02 03 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
01 01 02 03 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 01 02 03 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
01 01 02 03 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 03 01 02 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
01 03 01 02 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 01 02 03 04 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
01 01 02 03 04 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 01 02 03 04 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
03 01 02 03 04 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 03 01 02 04 00 00 00 0b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
01 03 01 02 04 00 00 00 0b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 02 03 01 04 00 00 00 0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

While it's clear that the correct data is being read, what I have been unable to determine is how to properly frame the data between the board and iOS device. Above, it appears that the data is not always received in the correct order (e.g. sequences of 03 02 03 can be found), and strange values appear as well (0c and 04?). I can't seem to make sense of why this would happen, or how to go about ensuring the data on the iOS device is read from the device in order. Can someone provide any insight into why the data looks like it does above, or general Arduino serial data writing rules that can be used to ensure proper data framing?

EDIT:

On the iOS side, I'm getting the data from CoreBluetooth via the delegate function

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
```

And the NSData* I'm inspecting comes from characteristic.value.

Comment: How are you reading the data in iOS? Can you show that code, or at least your peripheral read method

Comment: @Paulw11 Updated the description with the relevant CoreBluetooth callback.

Comment: I haven't used the coin module but I had a look at their code on GitHub. It seems to expose a pair of attributes for the read/write data and another for buffer status.  One thing I note is that your arduino code is going to flood the send buffer very quickly and it doesn't check for a buffer full condition.  Also BLE is a relatively low-speed interface.  I would try writing your 3 bytes once rather than in the loop.

Comment: @Paulw11 Even when adding a delay(1000) at the end of each loop iteration, I still see similarly strange results.

Comment: Try writing just the 3 bytes (or even 1 byte) and then stop.  Which characteristic are you getting the data from?